# get a comma delimited string from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What will be the query in MS Sql Server to concatenate my rows in one string , delimited by comma (*Like shown below*)

[image: query to delimeter string]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle or SQL Server? And Have you tried something?

Comment: SQL SERVER, i have no idea how to do.....

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/1530987

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 11):

Use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx):

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('John'),
('Vicky'),
('Sham'),
('Anjli'),
('Manish')
```

The query:

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + Name
    FROM @T
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') As [output];
```

Results:

```
output
John,Vicky,Sham,Anjli,Manish
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming That your column name is `NAME` And table name is `MYTABLE` you can use  the Following query:

```
DECLARE @strTemp VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strTemp = ''

SELECT @strTemp  = @strTemp + ISNULL(NAME,'') + ','
FROM MYTABLE

--Remove last comma
SET @strTemp = SUBSTRING(@strTemp ,1,LEN(@strTemp ) -1)

--Get Result
SELECT @strTemp
```

You can filter null records using the following

```
SELECT @strTemp  = @strTemp + NAME + ','
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL
```