# How to return a comma separated values of column without having to loop through the result set

Tags: t-sql

Let say I have this 2 table

```
+----+---------+       +----+-----------+----------------+
| Id | Country |       | Id | CountryId | City           |
+----+---------+       +----+-----------+----------------+
| 1  | USA     |       | 1  |   1       | Washington, DC |
+----+---------+       +----+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | Canada  |       | 2  |   2       | Ottawa         |
+----+---------+       +----+-----------+----------------+
                       | 3  |   1       | New York       |
                       +----+-----------+----------------+
                       | 4  |   1       | Baltimore      |
                       +----+-----------+----------------+
```

I need to produce a result like:

```
Id | Country | Cities
---+---------+--------------------------------------
1  | USA     | Washington, DC, New York, Baltimore
---+------------------------------------------------
2  | Canada  | Ottawa
```

So far, I am looping through the left side table result like this:

```
DECLARE @table 
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
   CountryId INT,
   City VARCHAR(50)
 )

DECLARE @tableString
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
   CountryId INT,
   Cities VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT Id, City
FROM tblCountries

DECLARE @city VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @i INT = 1
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM @table

WHILE (@i <= @count)
  BEGIN
    SELECT @Id = Id, @city = City FROM @table WHERE Id = @i
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @tableString WHERE CountryId = @Id))  
      BEGIN
         UPDATE @tableString SET Cities = Cities + ', ' + @city WHERE Id = @Id
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tableString (CountryId, city) VALUES (@Id, @city)
      END
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END

  SELECT tc.Id, tc.Country, ts.Cities
  FROM tblCountries tc
  LEFT JOIN @tableString ts
  ON tc.Id = ts.CountryId
```

My concern is that with all those looping in TSQL, it may be a performance killer. Even with fewer, it appears to be slow. Is there a better way to concatenate those string without having to loop through the data set as if I was working in C#
.
Thanks for helping

Comment: See if these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Comment: @JeremyJ., am I missing something? It seems like this is related to XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get a comma delimited string from rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787834/get-a-comma-delimited-string-from-rows)

Comment: It seems strange on the surface, but using the FOR XML clause a common way to build a comma separated list in a select statement SQL Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you are using 2017 you should look into the [string aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function(s).

Answer (score 1):

This was answered many times, but I've got the feeling, that some explanation might help you...

> ... am I missing something? It seems like this is related to XML

The needed functionality [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) was introduced with SQL-Server 2017. The other direction [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) came with v2016.

But many people still use older versions (and will do this for years), so we need workarounds. There were approaches with loops, bad and slow... And you might use recursive CTEs. And - that's the point here! - we can use some abilities of XML to solve this.

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <element>text1</element>
    <element>text2</element>
    <element>text3</element>
</root>';
```

--The query will return the first `<element>` below `<root>` and return *text1*.

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/root/element)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

--But now try this:

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/root)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

The result is *text1text2text3*.
The reason for this: If you call `.value()` on an element without a detailed specification of **what** you want to read, you'll get the whole element back. Find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204).

Now imagine an XML like this

```
DECLARE @xml2 XML=
N'<root>
    <element>, text1</element>
    <element>, text2</element>
    <element>, text3</element>
</root>';
```

With the same query as above you'd get *, text1, text2, text3*. The only thing left is to cut off the leading comma and the space. This is done - in most examples - with [STUFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

So the challenge is to **create** this XML. And this is what you find in the linked examples.

A general example is this: Read all tables and list their columns as a CSV-list:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       TABLE_NAME
      ,STUFF(
       (SELECT ',' + c.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
        WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
        ORDER BY c.COLUMN_NAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,1,'') AS AllTableColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
```