# Failing to programmatically DROP primary keys > ALTER the type length of a specific primary key column > ADD them back as primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, alter, declare

I have to increase the length of a primary key which appears in several tables. I have to do this programmatically and do it in several databases.
I am almost there, and things work individually, but when I put everything together I get an error on the last line `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN)`

> Msg 1911, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
> Column name 'PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN' does not exist in the target table or view.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 30
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is the whole query

```
DECLARE @Col1Len varchar(100) = (SELECT character_maximum_length    
                                 FROM information_schema.columns  
                                 WHERE table_name = 'table1' 
                                   AND column_name = 'Col1')

IF (@Col1Len < 60)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @PKs TABLE (PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN varchar(100))

    INSERT INTO @PKs (PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN) (
        SELECT column_name AS PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
              ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
              AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
              AND KU.table_name = 'table1')

    SELECT * FROM @PKs

    DECLARE @PK varchar(100) = (SELECT name 
                                FROM sysobjects 
                                WHERE xtype = 'PK'
                                  AND parent_obj IN (SELECT id 
                                                     FROM sysobjects 
                                                     WHERE name = 'table1')
                               )

    DECLARE @Command varchar(100) = 'ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @PK
    EXECUTE (@Command)  

    ALTER TABLE table1 
        ALTER COLUMN Col1 varchar(40) NOT NULL

    ALTER TABLE table1 
        ADD PRIMARY KEY(PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN)
END
```

If I run just the block below, it works and it finds the primary keys and inserts them into @PKs Table.

```
    DECLARE @PKs TABLE (
        PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN varchar(100)
    )
    Insert into @PKs (PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN) (
        SELECT column_name as PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
            ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
            AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
            AND KU.table_name='table1'
    )
        SELECT * from @PKs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN)` if you already know that the column name is `col1`?

Comment: There may be more than 1 PK in the table, so I need to add them all back.

Comment: That's a composite primary key, not multiple primary keys - there can only be one

Comment: Oh I see. I also realise something dumb...if I increase the length I don't have to drop the constrain first! How can I have missed that? So problem solved I guess.

Comment: In that case, you might want to delete the question. (even though I can answer it if you'ld like me to)

Comment: Well, it would be really good to know how to do it in case the length needs to be decreased or the type changed, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because your `alter table` statement isn't related to the `@PKs` table variable. Also, in case of a composite primary key (meaning, a primary key that is the combination of multiple columns), you need to add it as a comma-separated list of column names -
i.e. `alter table add constraint pk_table primary key (col1, col2)` To do that, you'll need to build the alter table dynamically from the values in the `@PKs` table variable:

```sql
DECLARE @AddPK nvarchar(1000);
SELECT @AddPK = 'ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY(' + STRING_AGG(PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN, ',') +');'
FROM @PKs

ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT PK_table1;
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN Col1 nvarchar(10) NOT NULL;
EXECUTE(@AddPK);
```

Note: [`String_Agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) requires SQL Server 2017 (14.x) or later, if you're using an older version you'll have to use the old workaround of [`for xml` + `stuff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788610/3094533) to concatenate rows into a comma delimited string.

And a side note - instead of `varchar(100)` for `PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN` use [`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> `sysname` is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is functionally equivalent to `nvarchar(128)`, except that it isn't nullable. `sysname` is used to reference database object names.

Comment: I ended up with this, which works perfectly. 

```DECLARE @AddPK nvarchar(1000);
SELECT @AddPK = 'ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(' + STRING_AGG(PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN, ',') +');'
 FROM @PKs

DECLARE @Command varchar(100) = 'ALTER TABLE table1 DROP Constraint ' + @PK_Table1
EXECUTE (@Command) 
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN Col1 nvarchar(30) NOT NULL;
EXECUTE(@AddPK);```